# How to put images in an array in Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm making an app, and I want to implement a feature where an image is shown accordingly to which fragment is open.

I've 9 images I want to put in an array. I've made a String array where I used it like this:

```
String [] text = new String [5];
        text[0] = "hello";
        text[1] = "hey";
        ....
```

I want to do the same for the images I've. I've put the images in the mipmap folder. In a JFrame ImageIcon can be used for this, but what about in Android?

Comment: You can store the path of the images in an array.

Comment: Can you please show me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by 'images'.

Do you mean views on a screen? then you need `ImageView[]`. If you need references to image resources, then `@DrawableRes int[]` and then you can put `R.drawable.yourImage` there. If you need images in memory, then you can use `Bitmap[]`, but make sure you know how much memory you use, because having too many images in RAM may cause `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: I mean views on a screen, yes. It's written like this?:  `ImageView [] image = new ImageView[9];
        image[0] = R.mipmap.IMAGENAME`

Comment: `R.mipmap.IMAGENAME` is not a view on a screen, this is a reference to an image resource. You can store them in an `int[]` array: `int[] images = new int[9]; images[0] = R.mipmap.IMAGENAME` To display that image you will need a view on a screen, which is `ImageView`. It will look like `imageView.setBackgroundResource(images[i])` where `images` is your array with references to mipmap resources.